# Get filename from $@ in Makefile

Tags: c++, bash, makefile

this makefile works great when all the cpp files are in one directory.
upon creating subdirectories it fails to create the *.o files because its missing subdirectories:

## Directory Structure

```
.
├── Makefile
├── README.md
├── src
│   ├── Adventurer
│   │   └── Adventurer.cpp
│   ├── Board
│   │   ├── AdventureTile.cpp
│   │   └── Board.cpp
```

## Makefile

```
CC := g++ # This is the main compiler
SRCDIR := src
BUILDDIR := build
TARGET := bin/forbidden-island
 
SRCEXT := cpp
SOURCES := $(shell find $(SRCDIR) -type f -name *.$(SRCEXT))
OBJECTS := $(patsubst $(SRCDIR)/%,$(BUILDDIR)/%,$(SOURCES:.$(SRCEXT)=.o))
CFLAGS := -g -Wall
LIB := -lsfml-graphics -lsfml-window -lsfml-system 
INC := -I include


$(BUILDDIR)/%.o: $(SRCDIR)/%.$(SRCEXT)
# BUILDPATH=$($(BUILDDIR)/%.o) # missing step of creating subdirectories 
# OFILE=$(basename $@)
    @mkdir -p $(BUILDDIR)
    @echo " $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(INC) -c -o $@ $<"; $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(INC) -c -o $@ $<
```

an example output of this code is:

```
 g++  -g -Wall -I include -c -o build/Board/Board.o src/Board/Board.cpp
 src/Board/Board.cpp: In member function ‘AdventureTile Board::getTile(int, int)’:
 src/Board/Board.cpp:13:1: warning: no return statement in function returning non-void [-Wreturn-type]
}
^
Assembler messages:
Fatal error: can't create build/Board/Board.o: No such file or directory
Makefile:23: recipe for target 'build/Board/Board.o' failed
make: *** [build/Board/Board.o] Error 1
```

how can the command be changed so that it is just the name of the o file and not the full path. using the special variable $@.

`(basename $@)` returned `build/Board/Board` but need it to be board.o

### =============== Solution ===============

The Makefile was failing because the subdirectories were not created.
the line `@mkdir -p $(BUILDDIR)` needed to become `@mkdir -p $(dir $@)` to remedy this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't really understand what you mean by *how can the command be changed so that it is just the name of the o file* ... which command?

It's not correct for a recipe to create a file which is not exactly the value of `$@`.  That's what make expects you to create and things won't work correctly if your recipe creates some other file.

In any event the functions GNU make supports are [available here](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/File-Name-Functions.html).  The one you want is `$(notdir $@)`.  However you don't even need that, because there are variants of the [automatic variables](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Automatic-Variables.html) for the directory (`$(@D)`) and file (`$(@F)`).

Comment: Thank you. I didn't realize that the special functions were for GNU make. I thought they reffered to bash special variables.